# Github Pages Offline

Tags: github, github-pages

Recently (since Sept 24, 2018) I have noticed that in the mornings (US Eastern Standard Time approximately 8am - 12pm) that all of my static "websites" hosted using the /docs directory option for hosting Github Pages are offline. For the past week, I consistently get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error - this is true no matter which browser I'm using (Chrome, IE, Edge, etc).

I've posted several support requests with Github, but my connection to my repositories is fine so they are not really registering a problem on their end. But I have 3 University courses hosted using Github Pages that have been consistently offline for hours each day in the past week and a half. This is problem for my students.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Did something recently change in the Github protocol for hosting static websites using Github Pages via the /docs directory?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the pages in question?

Comment: To clarify, so your pages are only down between 8am and 12pm EST?

Comment: The websites are: https://melindahiggins2000.github.io/N736Fall2017/
https://melindahiggins2000.github.io/N736/
https://melindahiggins2000.github.io/N741bigdata/ and in general I've noticed they are "offline" in the morning but usually back online after lunchtime (US EST).

Comment: It's currently 8:21am Eastern and your pages are working fine for me.

Comment: 9:20 Eastern and still working.

Comment: Thank you. I did hear back from Github. It appears there is some issue with my local ISP. I'm investigating with them. But, yes, this morning everything seems to be working fine. Thank you for your time.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than an issue with GitHub. FWIW, the sites are still up at 11:38am Eastern.